Implement Searchkick with search_after and PIT (Point In TIme)
first of all, I have code like this
options = {order: {name: :asc}, per_page: 100, page: current_page}
products = Product.search("*", **options)

and encountered this error in ElasticSearch pagination after page 100
[400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Result window is too large, from + size must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [10100]. See the scroll api for a more efficient way to request large data sets.
I research about scroll_api for ElasticSearch and I founds out deep pagination with scroll_api is not recommended, then I found search_after mechanism from this official github
https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/blob/909de90bb8256273a823fb096e473c01601edaff/test/pagination_test.rb#L159-L222
and I learn that I need to use search_after with pagination for consistent sort,
Problem is I struggled to generate PIT with Searchkick, I used this code
pit_id = Searchkick.client.open_point_in_time(index: Product.search_index.name, keep_alive: "5s")["id"]

and I got the id from my local like "w9O1A...AAA=="
but when I tried the same script in my staging machine, I got error from rails c using ssh
/usr/local/bundle/gems/elasticsearch-transport-7.13.3/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:218:in `__raise_transport_error': [400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"request body is required"}],"type":"parse_exception","reason":"request body is required"},"status":400} (Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest)
what am I doing here? Do I use the right code ? And I think I'm still far away to implement PIT with my sorting based on name asc
Note: I'm using Rails 6.1.4.6 and ElasticSearch 7.13.3 with Searchkick gem
